# Understanding additivity of random measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, bayesian

Give $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and $(X, \mathcal{B}(X))$, $\mathcal{M} :=\{\mu | \mu \text { is measure on }(X, \mathcal{B}(X))\}$, then random measure $\mathbf{P}$ can be defined as transition kernel $\mathbf{P}: \Omega \times \mathcal{B}(X) \to \mathbb{R}_+$ or a random element takes values in $\mathcal{M}$.

I know the definition of measure requires countable additivity. So does the definition of $\mathbf{P}$ imply $\mathbf{P}$ is finite additive or countably-additive?I mean,given measurable **disjoint** subset of $X, A_1,...,A_n$ , random variable $\mathbf{P}(\cup_n A_n) = \sum_n \mathbf{P}(A_n)$ i.e. sum of random variable $\mathbf{P}(A_n)$? If so, can $n$ be $\infty$?

My question comes from original paper of *Dirichlet process*:**A Bayesian Analysis of Some Nonparametric Problems**,
 where it uses *finite additivity*(I am not sure finite additivity in the paper is assumption or the property of random measure)

Take  *Dirichlet process* as example, does this process satisfy finite additive or countably-additive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual definiton of a random measure requires countable additivity. If only finite additivity is assumed I think you should call your random measure a 'fintely additive random measure'.

Comment: I know the definition of *measure* requires countable additivity. You mean **random measure** also need  countable additivity as *measure*? It seems wikipedia [random measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_measure) doesn't state this condition

Comment: In the Wikipedia link you have given the word measure means countably additive measure. The article clearly says a random measure is a measure valued random element. I don't know how you concluded that the article does not assume countable additivity.

Comment: Sorry about that. Since $\mathbf{P}(A_n)$ is now *random variable*, this makes me  have concern about additivity of $\mathbf{P}(A_n)$